# How to make bolding text in the text widget work optimally?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

I want to make text bold work as intended, meaning for example when you want to make a selected word bold, but you mistakenly didn't select the whole word, and you left out the last letter, and then you want to correct that mistake and select the whole word, instead of bolding the word, it will change its weight to normal. Specifically I'm talking about this way of doing this:

`

```
def bold_it():
    bold_font = font.Font(my_text, my_text.cget("font"))
    bold_font.configure(weight="bold")

    my_text.tag_configure("bold", font=bold_font)


    current_tags = my_text.tag_names("sel.first")

    if "bold" in current_tags:
        my_text.tag_remove("bold", "sel.first", "sel.last")
    else:
        my_text.tag_add("bold", "sel.first", "sel.last")
```

`

I am fully aware of what the problem is, and it is in the `current_tags` variable, since the variable will return "bold" because `tag names` only looks at tags which are at the first selected position. In turn, this will make the if statements remove the bold tag instead of applying it.

So my question is, how do you fix this, or optimize this?

Codemy.com did a video on this, and this question is based on this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6zqePBPDVU.

I tried utilizing the  `tag_ranges()` method so I could get two indexes instead of just where the selecting begins, but it did not work because `tag_names()` accepts only one argument.

Comment: You have selection `.first` and `.last` available. And you can read the text. It sounds like your requirement is "bolding shall always cover an entire word", not just part of a word. So doesn't this problem boil down to assigning local `first` & `last`, then walking `first` leftwards till we find a word boundary, and similarly walking `last` rightward until boundary?

Comment: Yes, I can use those selections, and with them I add tags to whatever I have selected, but the problem is the `tag.names()` method, it only accepts one index, and the if statements check whether that position has the "bold" tag or not. So if we want to bold the word "hello", and by mistake do it like **hell**o and leave out the last letter, when we attempt to select the whole word correctly to fix it, the first letter DOES have "bold" in it, and the `if` statement passes, making the word "hello" un-bolded.

Comment: OIC, the trouble is that the API doesn't let you pick arbitrary first & last offsets which you choose at word boundaries. Rather, you're stuck with the current pair of values in effect when your code gets called. Sigh! Maybe append the current word and its offset to a list, which we use for scheduling a "fix up" edit a little later? (I'm just looking for wiggle room in what the API allows us to do.)